# SELECT on empty table on Azure SQL Server takes a long time to finish even with non clustered index

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Situation: Azure SQL Server database (20 DTUs) with around 20% of space used. No other processes are running queries and the Compute utilization chart shows a solid line on 0%.

We have an empty table with around 80 columns. No indexes created. We have a query like this

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       ...
       columnN
FROM table
WHERE column1 = "some" 
  AND column2 = "something" 
  AND column3 = "something" 
  AND column4 = "something"
```

On the `WHERE` clause, we are using 4 columns (one of them is a `Timestamp` column).

When we run this query, after several minutes of running, we kill the process as it never ends, with the database CPU at 100%. As I said, the table is empty.

I created a non clustered index like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index_name] 
ON [dbo].[table] ([column1] ASC, [column2] ASC, 
                  [column3] ASC, [column4] ASC)
         WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
               ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

After creating the index, the same query takes several minutes to finish (again, with the CPU at 100%). The query execution plan just shows a `table scan`. My first question is, why do we get a `table scan` instead of an `index scan`? The index contains the 4 columns that are included on the `WHERE` clause.

However, if I create the same index but as a `CLUSTERED` one, the query finishes almost instantly and the execution plan shows an `index clustered seek`.

Why does a query over an empty table need a clustered index to conclude that is empty? Why it isn't enough to have a non clustered one?

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE.

The execution plan with [just the non clustered index](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJjHXo31n). Note: Since I already created a clustered index and dropped it to show this execution plan, now it is not an index scan anymore. It's an index seek. So it seems that the problem was indeed a heap issue.

The execution plan once the clustered index was created is [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S17kHo2k2).

Comment: We need to see the execution plan. Check out Paste The Plan.

Comment: The index only has four columns, the query asks for _all_ columns, so it is likely that the key lookups required to retrieve the columns not covered by the index are (at least as estimated by SQL Server) more expensive than just scanning the table and not needing any key lookups at all.

Comment: Also, why _don't_ you want a clustered index? Heaps have all kinds of special handling and side effects and it is widely considered a best practice to always have a clustered index on every table except in a few very niche cases involving bulk loading. In fact at one point in Azure SQL Database you couldn't even create a table without one. So, why don't you want to have a clustered index on every table?

Comment: The reason might very well be one of the side effects of having a heap. It's empty now, but was it always empty? The issue could be that you deleted a bunch of data but the pages haven't been deallocated so they still have to be read by any scan. Adding a clustered index essentially rebuilds the table and finally does that deallocation for you. Next time the scan of your heap gets slow even when it's empty, instead of creating a clustered index, drop the table and re-create it, or issue `ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD;`.

Comment: More details on that issue https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sqlskills-sql101-why-does-my-heap-have-a-bunch-of-empty-pages/

Comment: The moral of the story really is, in almost all cases, if you're having an issue with a heap, stop using a heap.

Comment: Well, the question is, did it have a lot of rows to start with?

Comment: @DaleK I have updated the question with the execution plan in both cases

Comment: @Stuckat1337 Regarding your second comment, maybe I didn't explain myself well. I didn't say that I don't want a clustered index. I was just asking why a non clustered index was not helpful in this case. The table was not empty before, so I think you're right about the heap. I was not thinking about that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: A poor screenshot of the query plan is not helpful. Please share via https://pastetheplan.com. If you need to sanitize it you can use SentryOne Plan Explorer, or do it manually in the XML.

Comment: We can see in the screen shot that it took 6mins 20 seconds and did a scan of the heap. I think it is pretty likely that the issue was deallocated pages in a heap. If you select the table scan operator in SSMS and look at properties what was the "Actual logical reads"? Also what was the "Estimated subtree cost" of that scan? Is maybe a bit strange that this would be costed lower than the index seek + 0/1 lookups - except if these deallocated pages aren't reflected in the costs - or just share the plans via paste the plan so we can look for ourselves and don't have to ask these questions

Comment: @MartinSmith, Charlieface, Stuck at 1337  I pasted the plans. I explained it on the question but since I created the clustered index and then dropped it to show the execution plan with and without the index, now the query without the clustered index is not a scan anymore. So indeed it seems that the creation of the clustered index rearranged the heap and solved the issue. Thank you for pointing me on the right direction! If any of you want to write any of your comments as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: So you no longer have the XML for the scan that you posted the image of earlier? (with the 6min 20 table scan?)

Comment: It should be @Stuckat1337 posting the answer IMO anyway

Comment: @MartinSmith No, sorry. I took the picture I posted before days ago. Now, with just a non clustered index, I don't get a table scan anymore. And it takes milliseconds, not minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The estimated plans don't confirm it but this is almost certainly a case where the heap was once large and is still holding onto a lot of pages that haven't been deallocated since those rows were removed.

This symptom is particularly prevalent with heaps and, as Martin pointed out, Paul Randal wrote about it here:

- [SQLskills SQL101: Why does my heap have a bunch of empty pages?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sqlskills-sql101-why-does-my-heap-have-a-bunch-of-empty-pages/)

Adding a clustered index resolves the issue because it has to completely rebuild the table, and at that point can finally deallocate the empty pages. And the symptom would still stay away even if you drop the clustered index and add a non-clustered index, because those deallocated pages are gone forever. However, if you keep *just* a non-clustered index, and fill the table up over time, and again clear it out, you're going to run into the same issue again.

*Only* adding a non-clustered index (without first creating a clustered index or otherwise forcing a rebuild) doesn't solve the problem because that doesn't rebuild the table like adding a clustered index does. So the pages still don't get deallocated.

You could also resolve the symptom by dropping the empty table and re-creating it (if it is in fact empty), or - whether it is empty or not - manually rebuilding it:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyHeap REBUILD;
```

However, to prevent the symptom from happening at all, I just wouldn't use a heap. Create the clustered index and *leave it there*.